# Multi level Sharding in Cassandra

Tags: sharding, cassandra

I am sorry if this is basic question. I am new to Cassandra and need help on a query.

Assume I want to host a service which accepts SurveyMonkey , now users are given a URL to take the survey and at backend results are stored in DB for persistence.

I have Cassandra DB with following Entities:

User ID - User Location -  Survey ID - Survey Content - URL - Survey response

User ID and Location is of user who created the survey.

Now I want to provide least latency to users taking this survey from all over the world. How should I Shard my DB so that some Shards are placed closest to user location and user gets ack once data is written to local quorum and then it can be synched to other locations.

EDIT:

Approach 1:

I will shard it on user ID and have local rep factor as 3 and 3 nodes at each DC location can be asynchronously be updated. Now when the request for write hits any of those other DCs then again they will search for concerned nodes based on user hash and after local quorum is satisfied then user will get ack and Db will asynchronously replicate on other Dc locations.

Approach 2:

Is there a way we can get user location who creates survey and then shard our DB based on location/region as majority of survey respondents may be from that region itself and then these DB nodes can replicate data to other DCs. In this approach is it possible to further shard data based on user id in each region ? Or the approach 1 looks good ?

Comment: you need to organize your cluster into a separate data centers, and use NetworkTopology for replication of your keyspace

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have edited my post with 2 approaches. COuld you please comment if approach 1 is good enough or in Approach 2 we can multi level shard DB for efficiency ?

Comment: it's not how Cassandra works.  It replicates all data that exist in the keyspace, not individual data. to have true separation, you will need to have different keyspaces with different replication settings

Comment: Aim is not seperation, rather just to give low latency to users in different regions taking those surveys. So that App server once accepts response from those users in their region can quickly sync that info in DB and ack the user. Then after a while when data is replicated in all regions the user who created this survey will query DB nearest to his region and view the survey results

Comment: that's a standard functionality of Cassandra - what I wrote in the first column